# maven plugin repository for eclipse equinox KeplerSR1

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, equinox, eclipse-kepler

Currently I'm trying to build my maven project which requires plugins from latest equinox KeplerSR1 release. So I'm looking for pluginRepository for eclipse-kepler SR1 release but could not find it.

I found this mirror url [1] but did't know how to use it to build my maven module.

Appreciate if someone can provide this.

[1] http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/eclipse/equinox/drops/R-KeplerSR1-201309111000/

Answer (score 0):

Equinox does not maintain maven plugin repository for vendors. I had to manually deploy the plugins to a maven repository which I'm using on my organization.